# Agora Channels : How to get the list of channels that are live in Agora RTC?

Tags: agora.io

We are building a clubhouse kind of app which has multiple live channels. How do we get the list of live channels on a real time basis ? We are developing on the Android Platform

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Online channel statistics query restful API here to get all the channels:
https://docs.agora.io/en/rtc/restfulapi